sqlcmd fails with Incorrect syntax near ';' after upgrading to .NET 8
We upgraded from .NET 6 to .NET 8 and now the dotnet-ef tool generates newlines in between, which the sqlcmd doesn't like. It's an Azure SQL database with compatibility level 150.
dotnet ef migrations script --project hidden --startup-project hidden  
       --output AppDbContext.sql --context AppDbContext --verbose --idempotent

sqlcmd -S "hidden" -d "hidden" -U "hidden" -P "hidden" -i "D:\AppDbContext.sql"


Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server hidden, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near ';'

I ran the SQL manually and it seems like it doesn't the empty BEGIN...END:
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM [Historical].[EFMigration]
    WHERE [MigrationId] = N'20210814000018_AddSPHedgeReport'
)
BEGIN




END;
GO

EF 6 didn't use to generate this.
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace hidden
{
    public partial class AddSPHedgeReport : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string?>(
                name: "FixedProperty",
                schema: "Reports",
                table: "SectionColumn",
                nullable: true);
            migrationBuilder.RunScripts("20210813");

        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "FixedProperty",
                schema: "Reports",
                table: "SectionColumn");
        }
    }
}

Another one that fails:
#nullable disable

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace hidden
{
    public partial class AuditTables : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.RunScripts("20220920");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
        }
    }
}

Here is what ScriptHelper does:
public static class ScriptHelper
{
    public static void RunScripts(this MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder, string version)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourceNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Where(str => str.EndsWith(version + ".sql"));
        foreach (var resourceName in resourceNames)
        {
            using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var sql = reader.ReadToEnd();
                migrationBuilder.Sql(sql);
            }
        }
    }
}


Those SQL statements are effectively identical, there's no reason for either to fail.

@DavidG updated. It's the empty BEGIN END;

So what you're actually stating is that EF now generates an IF with nothing inside said IF?

@ThomA, yes. Nothing has changed in the migration files. Only .NET and EF Core versions were upgraded 6 -> 8.

I'm not actually sure how EF could even generate that, since an empty migration wouldn't even have that block in it. What does the 20210814000018_AddSPHedgeReport migration actually do?

Does the created migration actually contain anything

@DavidG, I'm not sure either. I just shared the migration code

@phuzi, yes. I just shared the migration code.

Do any of the previous migrations use the script helper?

Hi nop, change your ScriptHelper like this link and tell us the result.

@phuzi, everything is literally the same. I just used WinMerge to compare both branches .net 6 vs .net 8.

@phuzi, I just did, but nothing seems to have changed. Please note that I only updated the ScriptHelper class and didn't modify anything in the migrations, after which I generated a new migration script that I ran directly in SSMS since it shows me which lines of code are problematic.

Can you check exactly why SQL string is being extracted by the RunScripts method?

@JasonPan If the sql string was empty, then the migrationBuilder.Sql would throw an exception anyway.

@DavidG, it is caused by the ScriptHelper because when I commented out migrationBuilder.RunScripts("20210813"), it's gone. Here is what the contents of the "..._20210813.sql" is: https://pastebin.com/e20HUJFz. Not all of the migrations that involve the ScriptHelper class are generating empty BEGIN-END, which means it's probably something in the .sql file that's referenced by the RunScripts method call

I meant, what is in the actual sql variable though, it could be that your RunScripts method is pulling out something odd, you should debug that.

Another thing to check, which version of EF are you using and is it up to date?

@nop Try this update one again. Thanks for your patience.

@JasonPan That code is pointless and is potentially going to break the SQL being executed as it requires BEGIN and END to be in there. The issue isn't that the SQL being executed contains an empty BEGIN/END block, it's that EF is generating one.

@JasonPan, I believe I just got it to work. Testing the pipelines right now, but it worked locally. https://pastebin.com/0QQWZrBm -> I just added .Trim()

@JasonPan, it worked. Finally! Could you submit https://pastebin.com/0QQWZrBm as an answer as you were the one who suggested the change. It just needed Trim()

Hi nop,  done. Thanks for your kindness, have a great day.

Thank you very much as well, and have a great day/evening!

Using the Trim() method effectively removes leading and trailing whitespace from SQL scripts, enhancing their compatibility and preventing format-related errors during execution.
public static class ScriptHelper
{
    public static void RunScripts(this MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder, string version)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourceNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Where(str => str.EndsWith(version + ".sql"));
        foreach (var resourceName in resourceNames)
        {
            using var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
            using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            //Removes white spaces or characters specified in an array of characters from the beginning and end of a string.
            var sql = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
                
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sql))
            {
                migrationBuilder.Sql(sql);
            }
        }
    }
}

